# Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have to convert a video to gray format first, then to hsv but I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/eycan/Desktop/serittakip.py", line 8, in <module>
    im = cv2.cvtColor(vid, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # grayscale kopya
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Users\\eycan\\Desktop\\serit\\yol.mp4")

while 1:    #frame cektıgımız ıcın whıle dongusune soktuk resım olsaydı boyle olmazdı
    _,frame = vid.read()
    im = cv2.cvtColor(vid, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # grayscale kopya
    vid = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #bgr dan hsv ye donusturduk

    lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 212])
    upper_white = np.array([131, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(vid,lower_white,upper_white)
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    cv2.imshow("MASK",mask)
```

Pls help :/

Answer (score 1):

- The first problem is you need to convert `frame` to the gray-scale object.

  - ```py
    im = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ```
- The second problem is when you convert from `BGR2HSV` please use different variable, other than `vid`, since `vid` is reading the next video frame.

  - ```py
    im_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    ```
- Also, please do change the rest of the `vid` variable with the `im_hsv`

  - ```py
    mask = cv2.inRange(im_hsv,lower_white,upper_white)
    ```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("C:\\Users\\eycan\\Desktop\\serit\\yol.mp4")

while 1:    #frame cektıgımız ıcın whıle dongusune soktuk resım olsaydı boyle olmazdı
    _,frame = vid.read()
    im = cv2.cvtColor(frane, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # grayscale kopya
    im_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) #bgr dan hsv ye donusturduk

    lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 212])
    upper_white = np.array([131, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(im_hsv,lower_white,upper_white)
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    cv2.imshow("MASK",mask)
```

Comment: You are great, it worked fine, but the only problem I guess is the video is not black and white. Apart from that, how can I just gray out the video?

Comment: Thanks :), you have already converted to the gray-scale, the variable `im` stored it. If you mean displaying the video as grayscale, just change `cv2.imshow("Frame", im)` then you should see the result in grey-scale